# How to remove encrypted ubuntu 14.04 OS from SSD

Tags: encryption, ssd

I installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS but I've decided its not for me.
During the install I was prompted to use disk encryption and I chose to do so and I had to Use a Passpharse to unlock the SSD prior to login. 
I couldnt find a way to remove this before so I re-installed ubuntu without incryption and it prompted me that it would Format the SSD and I would Lose everything that was on it(which is what I wanted anyways) but, it seems after the re-install was done. there was a protion of the SSD that was not deleted. Ubuntu OS was supposed to only take up 6.5GB and I have 256GB SSD. but after the re-install I only had 233GB, Im guessing the encrypted part of the previous Ubuntu install couldnt be deleted and now I'm stuck with less memory. can anyone help with this I want to remove Ubuntu completly off my SSD leaving it back to factory settings. how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1 boot live CD/USB

2 Choose try Ubuntu

3 Click the Ubuntu icon in the top left

4 Search for Gparted

5 Now right click on the drive you want and choose "unmount" if it only says mound ignore this step.

6 Right click it again and choose delete

7 Right click one more time and choose format then ntfs MAKE SURE TO SET PARTITION TYPE TO PRIMARY.

8 Now click the green tick on the tool bar to apply these changes

After this your disk should be clean

Comment: I reached this point but I am unable to remove any of these files from the SDD I dont see a format button or option

Comment: Updated my answer with more detail for you